# show text and image form json in image url?

Tags: android

```
 "status": true,
  "data": {
    "teachers_per_page": 15,
    "teachers_show_from": 0,
    "teachers_found": 142,
    "teachers": {
      "0": {
        "id": "249",
        "name": "MD. SHAHJAHAN KABIR",
        "position": "Assistant Professor",
        "department": "Computer Science And Engineering",
        "campus": "Green Road",
        "mobile": "01719005174",
        "email": "Kabir.cse@diu-bd.net",
        "photo": "http://www.diu.ac/ephoto/11384247470513269340.jpg",

        "Offday": "monday"
      },
      "1": {
        "id": "247",
        "name": "Bushra Ferdousi",
        "position": "Assistant Professor",
        "department": "Business Administration",
        "campus": "Banani"
        "mobile": "01911519737",
        "email": "Bushra.bba@diu-bd.net",
        "photo": "http://www.diu.ac/ephoto/11384247160483915267.jpg",

        "Offday": "monday"
```

hey guys this is my json data.how can show text and image from multi image url

Comment: you should first give a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

"***teachers***" should better be a jsonArray. This way you will not need to be numbering objects inside.

Now to answer you.
Suppose the root of your json is a jsonObject.

`JSONObject root = ...//
JSONObject data = root.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject teachers = data.getJSONObject("teachers");
JSONObject teacher = teachers. getJSONObject("0");`